# Configuring custom admin routing

Tags: magento2, admin, routing

I'm having some issues setting up admin routing.

My `menu.xml` file is as follows, note the custom route /manufacturer/grid.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Amrita_Manufacturer::manufacturers_second_level"
         title="Manufacturers"
         module="Amrita_Manufacturer"
         sortOrder="9999"
         resource="Amrita_Manufacturer::manufacturer"
         parent="Magento_Catalog::inventory"
         action="/manufacturer/grid"
    />
</menu>
```

`routes.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="manufacturer" frontName="manufacturer">
            <module name="Amrita_Manufacturer" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

and my `Index.php` file is located in the following directory  `Amrita\Manufacturer\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid`

Am i doing something wrong, I've tried a number of different suggestions and the menu link just redirects to the dashboard page?

Comment: What happens if you change your `action` to `manufacturer/grid/index` ?

Comment: try removing the slash at the beginning of your `action` in `menu.xml`

Comment: Gave this a try and it did change the structure of the href in the menu, it went from http://amritanutrition.local.quba.co.uk/admin/admin/manufacturer/grid/key/cbef68acd1bb79af4644c73b598c08bdebeff8b160626b7009633376ae9e8024/ to http://amritanutrition.local.quba.co.uk/admin/manufacturer/grid/key/cbef68acd1bb79af4644c73b598c08bdebeff8b160626b7009633376ae9e8024/ but still redirects to the dashboard. Also adding /index to the action doesn't seem to work either :-(

Comment: Do you have an `_isAllowed` method in your action class?

Comment: Yes i do, but i'm still experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> having some issues setting up admin routing.

As per the Magento routing, The router is looking for **/manufacturer/grid/Index**  not **manufacturer/grid**. 
 This means admin Controller should be placed **root\app\code\Amrita\Manufacturer\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\Index.php**

Please refer the code added for quick reference.

\app\code\Amrita\Manufacturer\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="manufacturer" frontName="manufacturer">
        <module name="Amrita_Manufacturer" before="Magento_Backend" />
    </route>
</router>
```

\app\code\Amrita\Manufacturer\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<menu>
    <add id="Amrita_Manufacturer::amrita_manufacturergrid" title="Manufacturers" module="Amrita_Manufacturer" parent="" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Amrita_Manufacturer" action="manufacturer/grid" resource="Amrita_Manufacturer::amrita_manufacturergrid"/>
</menu>
```

\app\code\Amrita\Manufacturer\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\Index.php

```
namespace Amrita\Manufacturer\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

\app\code\Amrita\Manufacturer\view\adminhtml\layout\manufacturer_grid_index.xml

```
 <body>     
    <referenceContainer name="content">         
        <block class="Amrita\Manufacturer\Block\Adminhtml\Manufacturer\Grid" name="manufacturer_grid" template="manufacturer\grid.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>       
</body>
```

\app\code\Amrita\Manufacturer\Block\Adminhtml\Manufacturer\Grid.php

```
namespace Amrita\Manufacturer\Block\Adminhtml\Manufacturer;
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

}
```

Make the template as well as,
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this has resolved the issue, i think there was a problem in the index.php file where i specified the namespace. Thanks, Sophie